# SQL CLR - "Static" variable for the current context

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqlclr

I know the use of a static variable in your DLL is unsafe, but is there any way to have something similar, or a variable that only exists for the current context?

What I'm trying to do is create a UDF which takes a comma-separated string, and returns a table with *two* columns, one is the index/order of the value in the original string, the other is the value itself. The splitting is easy (there's plenty of examples on-line, my code is below), but getting the order seems impossible.

I've tried using an `IDENTITY` column, but they're disallowed ("Cannot use 'IDENTITY' column in the result table of a streaming user-defined function"), and using a static vaiable is a no-go. In a web project, you get `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`, is there anything similar for a SQL project? Or is there a better way to do what I'm looking for?

SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitToInt(@list nvarchar(MAX), @delim nchar(1) = N',')
RETURNS TABLE (Value int)
AS EXTERNAL NAME CompanyName.Functions.SplitToInt
GO
```

C#

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "SplitToIntFillRow")]
public static IEnumerable SplitToInt(SqlString str, SqlString separator)
{
    return str.Value.Split(!separator.IsNull && separator.Value.Length > 0 ? separator.Value[0] : ',');
}

public static void SplitToIntFillRow(object row, out int Value)
{
    Value = System.Convert.ToInt32((string)row);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use SQL table-function?

Comment: Basically you can't figure out how to retrieve original index?

Comment: The @list variable originates in C#, and I very basically need to do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (@list) ORDER BY @list`

Comment: (I'm currently doing this by building up an nvarchar in my Stored Procedure, and then EXEC()ing it, but I *hate* this method, and I also want to improve code efficiency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (funny how writing things down, walking away, and coming back makes you see the obvious)

SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitToInt(@list nvarchar(max), @separator nchar(1) = N',')
RETURNS TABLE (InLevelOrder int, Value int)
AS EXTERNAL NAME CompanyName.Functions.SplitToInt
GO
```

C#

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "SplitToIntFillRow")]
public static IEnumerable SplitToInt(SqlString str, SqlString separator)
{
    var s = str.Value.Split(!separator.IsNull && separator.Value.Length > 0 ? separator.Value[0] : ',');
    var rtn = new List<int[]>(s.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        rtn.Add(new[] { i, System.Convert.ToInt32(s[i]) });
    return rtn;
}

public static void SplitToIntFillRow(object row, out int InLevelOrder, out int Value)
{
    InLevelOrder = ((int[])row)[0];
    Value = ((int[])row)[1];
}
```

If anyone can improve on this, feel free to comment.

Comment: I would loop over the `str` value and yield in your `SplitToInt()` function so the results can be streamed. (A bit premature optimization maybe)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by what you've said

Comment: This is a good relevant blog post about it: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/26/faster-more-scalable-sqlclr-string-splitting.aspx